# How to delete a file from another directory in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: command-line, delete

I'm starting learning Linux Ubuntu commands, now I want to learn how to delete a file from another directory while I'm in a different directory.

For example, now I'm in `Documents` and want to delete a file `TEST` file that is in `Downloads`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to give the right path :)

To delete the `TEST` file in `~/Downloads` you could use

```
rm ~/Downloads/TEST
```

that would work from *anywhere* in the filesystem because it is an *absolute path*. It is a shortened version of the full path `/home/$USER/Downloads/TEST` (`$USER` is expanded to the name of the current user) because `~` is a shortcut for the home directory, in my case `/home/zanna`

The *relative path*, from `~/Documents` would be

```
rm ../Downloads/TEST
```

`..` specifies the parent directory of where you are now, and `Downloads` is a subdirectory of that directory. But you should be extra careful when using `rm` with relative paths, because it is easy to make a mistake and delete something you didn't intend to!

Answer (score 1):

Try this buddy :

```
rm -f /absolutepath/file1.a /absolutepath/file2.b
```

rm removes files, and -f forces it to (so that it wont stop, asking you if you want to delete the file). If this not in your home directory, prepend sudo.

```
rm -rf  /absolutepath/emptyOrNotFolder
```

Answer (score -1):

Best way delete directory file is " sudo rm -R ./file name " . first you check ls then you see delete files name then write file name and delet any directory file.

Comment: Don't recommend `sudo` without (a) a good reason, and (b) a strong warning. There's unlikely to be a good reason to use `sudo` to delete a file in the `~/Downloads` directory.